# How can i globally handle a user interaction?

Tags: flutter

I want to handle a user interaction globally.

what solution is best for it ?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste following code in init state your app's base view that has implemented [GestureBinding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/GestureBinding-mixin.html).

```dart
@override
void initState() {
GestureBinding.instance.pointerRouter.addGlobalRoute(_globalUserInteractionHandler);
    super.initState();
  }

_globalUserInteractionHandler(PointerEvent event) {
    print("user interaction detected. $event");
  }
```

Comment: i was searching for this for a while , you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling actions anywhere in the app is by using [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). This [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) has a complete sample on app state management using `provider`.